# HTTP 400 - URL -

Tags: http, unix, iis, model-view-controller

I have a MVC site with a Controller with a couple of methods for a partner to post to. 
I can post to the web server from my local machine, across the WAN successfully.

My partner tries to post from his UNIX Server and it always results in HTTP 400 - URL.

I know the URL is good, and I know the response is good because I can post to it from multiple different network, but I am always posting from Windows.

He is posting:

```
POST domain.com/controllerName/action HTTP/1.0
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 136 
(Content-Length will be off because I changed the Request Body data for security purposes)

Parm1=Value1%0d%0aParm2=Value2%0d%0aParam2=Value3%0d%0a
```

I can take his data and post it from a Windows machine to the server just fine.

We were looking at the HTTP 1.0 value (this can't be changed from his side) and if perhaps IIS 8.5 on Server 2012 R2 was having an issue with it.

Has anyone had an experience like this? If so, do you have any information on how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: HTTP Error Log has entries like: 2016-08-24 02:35:02 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 37090 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80 HTTP/1.0 POST domain.com/controllerName/action 400 - URL -

Comment: I have tried Failed Request Tracing Rules, but it is like the request never makes it that far

Comment: I can post from hurl.it and requestmaker.com just fine. Still getting the HTTP 400 from Unix Server

Comment: No one has any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In the event that someone else has an issue like this, I will post the solution.

The code from my partner's Unix machine was opening a connection to domain.com 
Then when it posted it was posting to domain.com/controller/action.

However, after some careful research and tracing, I discovered the Windows server was seeing it as domain.com/domain.com/controller/action. 
Hence the 400 URL error in the log.

To solve the problem we updated on the Unix machine to open the connection to domain.com and then post to /controller/action.

Problem Solved.